# Is it possible to remove/ignore Pull request merges during git filter-repo? How do it do it?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-filter-branch, git-filter-repo

I am trying to move a folder from RepoA into RepoB with git and file histories. Using git filter-repo for the purpose as below

> git filter-repo --path src/test

However doing so includes all the Pull Request Merge commits along with fix commits like below

```
>Merge PR #65 from origin/br1
>Fix commit 1
>Merge PR #64 from origin/br1
>Fix commit 2
>Merge PR #63 from origin/br1
>Fix commit 3
```

Is it possible to ignore these Merge PR commits and filter out only the fix commits using git filter-repo ?

Comment: Those commits store a new, different version of that file and/or are important to history, so no, you can't do that—at least, not with `--path`. You *can* provide a different *filter* that *does* do that (but I'm not familiar enough to know if filter-repo provides one for you or if you will have to write a lot of Python code yourself).